# ssh -w bad tun device

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to create an SSH tunnel using the `-w` flag. I have 3 devices, for the sake of this question, I'll call them cmp1, cmp2, and cmp3. cmp1 is the device I am using, cmp2 is the jump server, and cmp3 is the destination. This is the command I'm running:

`ssh cmp2 -w cmp1[:cmp3]`

when I run this I get the error "bad tun device". I'm sure it's just me misunderstanding how the command works, but I just don't know how to get it working. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem by using a different method. This is the command I used instead:

`ssh -N -L 3333:cmp3:22 cmp2`

This allowed me to switch to another terminal and ssh via localhost on port 3333.